# insert rows for missing values of datetime series in pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, resampling

I have some time series, recorded in 1 minute time steps without records, if the value of x is 0.
The data file looks like this:

`Date;Time;x
20.02.2020;00:00:00;0.1
20.02.2020;00:03:00;0.4
20.02.2020;00:04:00;0.3
20.02.2020;00:05:00;0.3
20.02.2020;00:07:00;0.2`

I want to fill in the missing records having x=0.0. The expected result is:

`Date;Time;x
20.02.2020;00:00:00;0.1
20.02.2020;00:01:00;0.0
20.02.2020;00:02:00;0.0
20.02.2020;00:03:00;0.4
20.02.2020;00:04:00;0.3
20.02.2020;00:05:00;0.3
20.02.2020;00:06:00;0.0
20.02.2020;00:07:00;0.2`

I tried:

```
import pandas as pd

with open('data.csv') as csv_file:
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, delimiter=';',parse_dates={'datetime': ['Date', 'Time']})
df.set_index(['datetime'])
df.asfreq(freq='1Min', fill_value=0.0)
```

And I get:

`datetime   x
1970-01-01  1970-01-01  0.0`

No error message. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your `set_index` operation is not happening in place, best is to chain your methods:

```
df.set_index('datetime').asfreq('1min', fill_value=0).reset_index()
```

Or with `resample`:

```
df.set_index('datetime').resample('1min').first().fillna(0).reset_index()
```

```
             datetime    x
0 2020-02-20 00:00:00  0.1
1 2020-02-20 00:01:00  0.0
2 2020-02-20 00:02:00  0.0
3 2020-02-20 00:03:00  0.4
4 2020-02-20 00:04:00  0.3
5 2020-02-20 00:05:00  0.3
6 2020-02-20 00:06:00  0.0
7 2020-02-20 00:07:00  0.2
```

---

Or fix your own code:

```
df = df.set_index('datetime')
df.asfreq(freq='1Min', fill_value=0)
```